# SQL to build heirarchy string - last level missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, hierarchy

I am building a string for the hierarchy of a document management system.  So, basically the folder by folder breakdown - all the way to the document.

Two problems:

1.The database lists all of the folders (and their parent) in one table, and all of the documents in another (and their parent folder)
2.The query I am using so far misses out the final folder level.

I am using the following query:

```
select a.id_object, a.name, a.id_parent, 
b.name as 'parent_name', b.id_parent as 'parent id'  
into #a
FROM [folders] a  left join  [folders] b on b.id_object = a.id_parent
```

then:

```
INSERT INTO Tree2([id_parent],[parent_name],[id_object],[object_name])
select id_parent, [parent_name],id_object, [name]  from #a
```

then to find the absolute top level and insert a `/`:

```
UPDATE Tree2 SET Lineage='/', Depth=0 WHERE parent_name Is Null
UPDATE Tree2 SET Full_Lineage='/', Depth=0 WHERE parent_name Is Null
```

Then the recursive part:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tree2 WHERE Depth Is Null) 
UPDATE T SET     T.depth = P.Depth + 1, 
         T.Lineage = P.Lineage + T.id_parent + ' / ' ,
         FROM Tree2 AS T 
INNER JOIN Tree2 AS P ON (T.id_parent=P.id_object)
WHERE P.Depth>=0 
AND T.Depth Is Null
AND P.Lineage Is Not Null
```

This then brings my data to look like this:

```
Node    id_parent     id_object    object_name    depth    lineage      
100     f10101        f1010122       blah blah      5        F00/f0/f100/f1000/f10101
```

Can anyone suggest how to include the final folder level on the end of the lineage, as `f1010122`  is the last folder in the chain and still needs to be included in the `lineage` column?  And then I had intended on a left join of the documents table where `document_parent_id = id_object (f1010122)`.

Hope this makes sense. I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the current `id_object` at the end of its lineage, then that would be a fairly simple:

```
Select node, id_parent, id_object, object_name, depth, lineage, 
    full_path = lineage + id_object + '/'
  From Tree2;
```

In general, though, you could probably achieve what you're wanting to in a single step rather than the multi-step process you have here (which seems to have some bugs in it, possibly because you tried to recreate your code for the purpose of posting it here: buggy samples do make answering harder).

The following sample goes directly from your source `[folders]` table and returns the output you want in a `SELECT` statement (which you could insert into a table, if you want):

```
With recursive_cte As (
    Select id_object, name, id_parent, 
        depth = 0, 
        lineage = Convert(varchar(128), '/')
      From [folders]
      Where id_parent Is Null
    Union All
    Select child.id_object, child.name, child.id_parent, 
        depth = parent.depth + 1, 
        lineage = Convert(varchar(128), parent.lineage + child.id_parent + '/')
      From [folders] As child
      Join recursive_cte As parent on child.id_parent = parent.id_object)
Select id_object, name, id_parent, depth, lineage,
    full_path = lineage + id_object + '/'
  From recursive_cte;
```

Comment: Thankyou @mendosi, I get where you are coming from, however am getting a "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "lineage" of recursive query "recursive_cte" " error message.  have googled it but don't seem to be able to solve it.  Any ideas, and thankyou for your help so far.

Comment: @user3735855 If you do `Select @@VERSION`, what version are you on? 2014?

Comment: @user3735855 It may help for you to include the definition of `[folders]` table in the question.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
 Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Thankyou @mendosi, I don't get that error when running directly on that server - (was running on a linked server).  Thankyou for your time.  cheers